# List comprehention works but normal for loop doesn't - Python

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, list-comprehension

I defined a function to change an element of a list to be number 0, if this element is not a number. It works using list comprehension but it doesn't work when I use a normal `for` loop.
I'm trying to understand what's is the error in the `for` loop.

See the code below:

```
def zerozero(mylist):
    
    mylist = [0 if type(x) == str else x for x in mylist]
    
    return mylist


def zerozero2(mylist):
    
    for x in mylist:
        if type(x) == str:
            x = 0
        else:
            x = x
    return mylist
```

Comment: Your for loop is not actually writing your results to a variable. The `myList = [...]` of the list comprehension constructs a new list. Your zerzero2 function is not actually doing anything to any list. The `x` variable goes out of scope and is dropped on each iteration.

Comment: in your second function you want to build a new list and in the for loop append to it then return it. at the moment, your for loop looks like it does something but ultimately it does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second function is not quite equivalent. You would need something like this:

```
def zerozero2(mylist):
    new_list = []
    
    for x in mylist:
        if type(x) == str:
            new_list.append(0)
        else:
            new_list.append(x)
    return new_list
```

In this manner you can mimic the functionality of the list comprehension, creating a new list and appending items to it as you iterate through.

If you want to modify your list 'in place', you can use this sort of construction:

```
for idx, x in enumearte(mylist):
    if type(x) == str:
            mylist[idx] = 0
        else:
            mylist[idx] = x
```

However, practically speaking this is unlikely to have much impact on your code efficiency. You can't do this with a list comprehension, and in either case you can just re-assign the new list back to your original variable when you return from the function:

```
mylist = zerozeroX(mylist)
```

Comment: Thanks. Can I return the new values into the original list using for loop? Like, replacing the string element with zero, instead of appending into a new list?

Comment: @AnaClaudia I've updated the response!

Answer (score 1):

So what happens is your function is returning the same list as your input.

What you should do is create an empty list first. For example my_list_0 = [].

```
def zerozero2(mylist):
    my_list_0 = []
    for x in mylist:
        if type(x) == str:
            x=0
        else:
            x=x
        my_list_0.append(x)
    return my_list_0
```

The list comprehension essentially returns the new values into your original list, so this is why it is different.

Comment: Thanks. Can I return the new values into the original list using for loop? Like, replacing the string element with zero, instead of appending into a new list?